# Magento PWA PDP pages are not loading ( redirecting user to 404 )

Tags: php, magento, progressive-web-apps

I am using Magento 2.4.4 with PWA studio 12.5.0.

PLP ( category pages working fine ) but PDP pages redirect users to 404. not sure what is happening & where I need to look. I am attaching some logs I found in the browser console & under Magento

Console Logs:-

```
{“errors”:[{“debugMessage”:“Expected a value of type \“Int\” but received: PRODUCT”,“message”:“Internal server error”,“extensions”:{“category”:“internal”},“locations”:[{“line”:1,“column”:75}],“path”:[“route”,“type”]}],“data”:{“route”:{“relative_url”:“url-product-1.html”,“redirect_code”:0,“type”:null,“uid”:“MTA4ODA4OA==“,”__typename”:“SimpleProduct”}}}
```

Magento debug logs:-

```
==> debug.log <==
[2022-07-06T18:09:47.677613+00:00] report.ERROR: Expected a value of type "Int" but received: PRODUCT

GraphQL (1:75)
1: query ResolveURL($url:String!){route(url:$url){relative_url redirect_code type ...on CmsPage{identifier __typename}...on ProductInterface{uid __typename}...on CategoryInterface{uid __typename}__typename}}
```

any help appreciated

some more details.

```
{errors: [{debugMessage: "Expected a value of type "Int" but received: PRODUCT",…}], data: {,…}}
data: {,…}
route: {relative_url: "epoxy-acrylic-resin-hazmat-item.html", redirect_code: 0, type: null, uid: "OTY2MTk=",…}
redirect_code: 0
relative_url: "producturl.html"
type: null
uid: "OTY2MTk="
__typename: "SimpleProduct"
errors: [{debugMessage: "Expected a value of type "Int" but received: PRODUCT",…}]
0: {debugMessage: "Expected a value of type "Int" but received: PRODUCT",…}
debugMessage: "Expected a value of type \"Int\" but received: PRODUCT"
extensions: {category: "internal"}
locations: [{line: 1, column: 75}]
message: "Internal server error"
path: ["route", "type"]
```

another log I found may help to resolve this

```
[GraphQL error]: Message: Internal server error, Location: [object Object], Path: route,type
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Magento community edition?

If Yes ,Please change In packages\venia-concept .env

Change the value to MOS

MAGENTO_BACKEND_EDITION=MOS

after that, you can search "aux" in config.php,

enable such modules, so you should able to add products in cart now.

Comment: I am using Magento cloud & my Backend Edition setting is 

MAGENTO_BACKEND_EDITION=AC

& I am not able to find aux module in config.php

Comment: Did you checked and run Graphql query of PDP page in chromiql ? Its working in chromiql or not .

You have added any new product attributes ?

Comment: Yes I checked Query ( urlResolver ) works fine just on PWA PDP not loading